# raise ValueError("Input contains NaN") ValueError: Input contains NaN when trying to build machine learning model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

I am trying to build a prediction model but currently keep getting an error: `raise ValueError("Input contains NaN") ValueError: Input contains NaN`. I tried to use `np.any(np.isnan(dataframe))` and `np.any(np.isnan(dataframe))`, but I just keep getting new errors. For example, `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`.

Here is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',')

le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = dataframe

dfle2 = dfle.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')

newdf = dfle2[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']]

X = dataframe[['column1', 'column2', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7']].values

y = dfle.column3

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
# np.all(np.isfinite(dfle))
# np.any(np.isnan(dfle))
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multiple things to deal with this error
first, you can fill the Nan values by 0 `dataframe = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=',').fillna(0)`

or you can use `sklearn` imputation  techniques to fill the Nan value.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute

Multiple Imputation techniques are available but you should use `KNNImputer`.

Comment: You can also df.dropna(), but I suppose it is less useful.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types,
and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

is probably because you're converting to `str` when doing `col.astype(str)`. Use something like `astype(float)` instead.

As for the `NaN` error, you need to figure if it's feasible to solve by just replacing it with zeros (`fillna(0)`) or if there is the need to go for something more complex like a Kalman filter for example.